# How to make gdb run a user-defined function (defined in .gdbinit) everytime it starts?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I have a set of basic breakpoints defined in a user-defined fn `setup` in my .gdbinit. So, every time i start gdb, I have to execute that fn. to set all my brkpoints , before I start debugging. Can I configure my .gdbinit so that whenever it starts , it first executes my user-defined fn `setup` ?

Comment: One can also accept arguments to those functions; passed as `$1`, `$2`, `$3` shell-style.

Comment: @ulidtko hmm no, that's $arg0, $arg1, etc...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli whoops, you're right!.. My bad. `$1` is for [History Values](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Convenience-Vars.html), probably worked for me "as expected" by pure coincidence. And `$arg0` etc, are as you say, arguments to [User-Defined Commands](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Define.html#Define). Good catch!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just call it by function name:

My .gdbinit:

```
define setup    
  echo Foobar\n
end   

setup #This is the function call
```

And when I run it:

```
$ gdb
GNU gdb Fedora (6.8-37.el5)
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
Foobar
(gdb)
```

Comment: Not working for me - gives this error:
.No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
/home/sbhowmick/.gdbinit:83: Error in sourced command file:
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/tls/libthread_db.so.1".

I'm using GNU gdb Red Hat Linux (6.3.0.0-1.138.el3rh)

Comment: My .gdbinit file looks like this:

define setup
   br fn1
   br fn2
end

define some_other_fn
  ...
end

setup

Comment: This is because you don't have the binary file loaded, if you are defining breakpoints, the binary must be loaded already when starting GDB, e.g. you must define "file a.out" or smtg like that in your .gdbinit before setting the breakpoints or run "gdb a.out" or so.

Comment: Is it possible to store those functions into the disk? So each time I debug on this project I don't need to re-type then again.

Comment: Use `gdb -x commands.gdb` to start `gdb`. For instance,

`file /path/to/exe
break foo.c:my_function
break bar.c:237
run
`